# PHP mail() returning FALSE but whole rainloop works - Postfix, Dovecot, PHP 7.3

Tags: php, email, postfix, sendmail, php.ini

I had this problem earlier but somehow managed to repair it.
One month after I had to reinstall Dovecot and Postfix and the same error appeared.

In my *php.ini* which is located at */etc/php/7.3/apache2/* is *sendmail_path* set to

*sendmail_path = /etc/postfix*

It writes I have a problem with permissions:

```
user@occamy:/etc$ sudo tail /var/log/mail.warn
Oct 21 16:27:36 localhost postfix/sendmail[20073]: fatal: /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf: file open failed: Permission denied
Oct 21 16:28:36 localhost postfix/sendmail[20079]: fatal: /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf: file open failed: Permission denied
Oct 21 16:35:02 localhost postfix/postfix-script[20270]: warning: symlink leaves directory: /etc/postfix/./makedefs.out
Oct 21 16:35:02 localhost postfix/postfix-script[20273]: warning: symlink leaves directory: /etc/postfix/./postfix_ab/makedefs.out
Oct 21 16:35:07 localhost postfix/sendmail[20328]: fatal: /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf: file open failed: Permission denied
Oct 21 16:35:32 localhost postfix/sendmail[20350]: fatal: /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf: file open failed: Permission denied
Oct 21 16:37:00 localhost postfix/postfix-script[20565]: warning: symlink leaves directory: /etc/postfix/./makedefs.out
Oct 21 16:37:00 localhost postfix/postfix-script[20568]: warning: symlink leaves directory: /etc/postfix/./postfix_ab/makedefs.out
Oct 21 16:37:07 localhost postfix/sendmail[20623]: fatal: /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf: file open failed: Permission denied
Oct 21 16:37:15 localhost postfix/sendmail[20625]: fatal: /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf: file open failed: Permission denied
```

**/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf**

I had the same problem with main.cf. I resolved it with chmod 775 which is not that good I guess...

Then it writes this permission error.
The weirdest thing on it is this progress I am doing to obtain e-mail:

1. Mail returns FALSE when sending mail()
2. Changing the whole *postfix* directory to perm. 775 and sending mail - returns TRUE
3. Email is not received
4. Changing back to all of the previous permissions for each file
5. Email has been magically received but cannot send it again. Aaand repeat from point 1

Also when I set *dynamicmaps.cf* to *chmod 775*, *sudo postconf -m* writes:

```
btree
cidr
environ
fail
hash
inline
internal
memcache
nis
pipemap
proxy
randmap
regexp
socketmap
static
tcp
texthash
unionmap
unix
```

and the *mysql* is missing with those permissions set.

Thank you in an advance for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

You've customized the `sendmail_path` parameter without knowing what it does.

From the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path):

> Where the **sendmail** program can be found, usually /usr/sbin/sendmail or /usr/lib/sendmail. **configure** does an honest attempt of locating this one for you and set a default, but if it fails, you can set it here.

You most likely don't need to tune it as it will work by default if all packages are from the package manager and if you do need to tune it, you certainly can't pass a folder as value.

The permission errors from postfix are likely because the file owners aren't properly setup. As a general rule of thumb, `chmod` or `chown` in `/etc` should be uncommon at least.

Comment: Okay, so I should leave sendmail_path blank

Comment: There is no change after that 

EDIT: PHP mail() is returning TRUE, only no e-mail has been received

Comment: You should leave it commented out, not blank as I'm not sure it is interpreted the same way.

Comment: Commented out, now mail() returns FALSE

Comment: /var/log/mail.err still returns dynamicmaps.cf file open failed: Permission denied

I still didn't set the permissions back for main.cf but I guess I'm going to obtain the same fatal err

Comment: List all the rights and owners of your postfix configuration. Did you restore it from a backup?

Comment: Yes, It's restored

Comment: Todays error says:
localhost postfix/sendmail[29797]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: Permission denied

Comment: Pleeease, still getting only permission error and can do nothing with that.